# No errors in console.log unless using try/catch

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, error-handling

Usually all errors will be shown in the browser console, for example if a variable is undefined. Not this time. No errors are shown unless I use try/catch.

I am not sure what the cause is. I started a new project and use webpack, babel and a bunch of other webpack relevant libraries. (list see bottom)

so the problem is:

```js
x = abc;
console.log("here");
```

"here" is not being shown because the code stops on that line. `x = abc`;
I don't see any compilation errors / warnings.

```js
try {
    x = abc;
} catch (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error.message);
}
console.log("here");
```

output:

```
Error: abc is not defined
here
```

Any idea why? Never had such an issue. And I don't have a wrapping try/catch.
Here are the stuff I load in package.json:

//EDIT:

This is the code I am using:

```js
abj.SomePromise().then((response) => {
    let c= aa;  //this should generate an error
    //this wont be shown:
    console.log('Everything loaded');
});
```

Comment: It looks like something else is catching the exception. Maybe window.onerror or something similar?

Comment: You can open up the debug console and type `console.log(window.onerror)` as a quick experiment.

Comment: I checked, window.onerror is null (document.onerror is also null)

Comment: Right, however I was just about to add that that's not necessarily conclusive, as a handler may have been added with `.addEventListener()`.

Comment: I just found out thats because I am using the error in a promise (in "then" part)

Comment: That is why is important to share the actual code instead of a piece of information that you think would be useful. I keep seeing this pattern everywhere developers that ask questions based on their on assumptions of what would be the error.

Comment: yeah  sorry about that :(

Answer (score 0):

Because the execution follows top to bottom approach,

**1st case**

```
x = abc;
console.log('here');
```

In the first case, your execution process will be stopped and killed because It's not handled, at that time your server will be crashed and got `ReferenceError: abc is not defined` in the console and `here` is not printed.

**2nd case**

```
try {
  x = abc;
} catch (error) {
  console.log(`Error: ${error.message}`);
}
console.log('here');
```

In this case, the error is properly handled  with `try/catch`,

**Explanation of 2nd case**

In this case it first execute whatever in `try{}` block, Then perform things whatever write in `try`, Here you make a variable `x` with value of `abc`, But `abc` is not defined, so it will `throw` an error, So here `catch() {}` block will come into the picture and perform whatever write in `catch() {}` block;
So It prints `Error: abc is not defined`, Then `try` and `catch` both are done his job; Then execution continuos to go bottom for further operations. It finds another log `console.log("here");` So it prints `here`.